# How do I port forward multiple SSH servers?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I am very new to networking and I have set up ssh on my raspberry pi. I also have ssh on my windows 10 computer. Here is my problem: I would like to have ssh port forwarding on both my raspberry pi and my Windows PC. I have a port forward for my pi with port 22, but if I want another port forward for my Windows PC, dont I have to use port 22 as the ending port again? I cant have more than one port using port 22 right? Are there other ending ports that I can use? Again, I am very new to networking so I know next to nothing about this matter. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad to answer as asked. Please edit you question to include a goos network description or diagram, the network device models, the network device configurations, etc.

Comment: just use a port other than 22